# Routing inside the tabs in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, routes, ionic4

I am trying to create the route inside the tabs. But I am not able to implement it. I have created the component inside one of my tab and I want to navigate to that component.
Below is my code

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { ReadingsPage } from './readings.page';
import { ReadingDetailComponent } from './pages/reading-detail/reading-detail.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children:[
      {
        path:'',
        component: ReadingsPage
      },
      {
        path:'detail',
        component:ReadingDetailComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [ReadingsPage,ReadingDetailComponent]
})
export class ReadingsPageModule {}
```

I am trying to navigate to my url using following function:-

```
showDetail(){
    this.router.navigate(['./detail'])
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@subhamvohra [enter link description here](https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-tabs-layout-with-angular-routing-and-ionic-4/)Try using following solution :- update children attribute with loadChildren with respective details

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/reading-detail/reading-detail.component' }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

you can get description on 
  [HelpforNestedRoute](https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-tabs-layout-with-angular-routing-and-ionic-4/)

Comment: But I think loadChildren works with modules only not components

Comment: you need to add that children for your main component which is holding your nested component, check with  link details.